# UIKIT upload - server side NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, getuikit

I'm trying to upload files throught UIKIT uploader and NodeJS. The problem is that I'm not able to get the file in the POST request.

**upload.controller.js**

```
UIkit.upload('.test-upload', {

      url: '/upload',
      multiple: true
      ...
})
```

**app.js**

```
app.post('/upload', function (req, res, next) {
  // How can I get the file here??
});
```

Comment: From the [docs](https://getuikit.com/docs/upload#component-options), I can see there is a param called "files[]", but still don't know how to get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to a `multipart/form` middleware to your Express app such as [multer](https://npmjs.com/packages/multer). Express doesn't support file uploading out of the box so you need to add multer to your middleware, normally on the route and not the whole server instance.

Multer can handle single or multi file uploads and can process form data as well for meta info about the uploads. You can read more about the various setups and storage settings in the docs.

```
const express = require('express')
const multer = require('multer')
const port = process.env.PORT || 1337
const server = express()
const upload = multer({dest: 'temp/' })

// process the array of "files"
server.post('/upload', upload.array('files'), (req, res) => {
  // work with files 
  console.log(req.files) // array of files

  // request body will be processed by multer as well
  console.log(req.body) 
})

server.listen(port, () => { console.log(`Listening on ${port}`) })
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked!!! :) Just one little thing... I had to rename the "name" param to:  `upload.array('files[]')` (default one by UIkit).